# Sequent Calculus

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, calculations

What is sequent calculus? See wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus

So basicaly I'd like to produce something like this:

[image: a sequent calculus]

Maybe using Tikz?

Comment: Could you show what you've tried so far? I'd be tempted just to use a `tabular`

Comment: nothing really, i'm quite a latex noob:). Tables sounds good, are nested tables possible? So a table in a table cell?

Comment: looks like `multicolumn` would do the trick. A thing I see missing: how to draw the rules? (the rules are the letters in parentheses next to a line)

Comment: Much as I love excessive uses of TikZ, I'm not sure it would help much here.

Comment: @brillout.com yes, nested `tabular` environments are possible. if you click on the `tables` tag in your question, you'll be taken to [a list of questions that also use it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables). have a look at them, as well as the not so short guide to latex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at

http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/

There are some packages described for teXing such sequences.
I would guess that the sequence you posted is done using proof.sty

Comment: We like answers on this site to be self contained. Could you add an example of using `proof.sty` to set a proof?

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answer is just a link I thought I'd show an example using the`bussproofs`package

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\newcommand{\implies}{\rightarrow}

\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{Axiom}
  \UnaryInfC{$\forall x [P(x)], \forall x [P(x) \implies Q(x)], Q(a) \vdash Q(a)$}

  \AxiomC{Axiom}
  \UnaryInfC{$\forall x [P(x)], \forall x [P(x) \implies Q(x)] \vdash P(a), Q(a)$}
  \RightLabel{$[\neg \vdash]$}
  \UnaryInfC{$\forall x [P(x)], \forall x [P(x) \implies Q(x)], \neg P(a) \vdash Q(a)$}

  \RightLabel{$[\lor \vdash]$}
  \BinaryInfC{$\forall x [P(x)], \forall x [P(x) \implies Q(x)], \neg P(a) \lor Q(a) \vdash Q(a)$}

  \RightLabel{$[\implies \vdash r.w.]$}
  \UnaryInfC{$\forall x [P(x)], \forall x [P(x) \implies Q(x)], P(a) \implies Q(a) \vdash Q(a)$}

  \RightLabel{$[\forall \vdash]$}
  \UnaryInfC{$\forall x [P(x)], \forall x [P(x) \implies Q(x)] \vdash Q(a)$}

  \RightLabel{$[\vdash \forall]$}
  \UnaryInfC{$\forall x [P(x)], \forall x [P(x) \implies Q(x)] \vdash \forall x [Q(x)$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

Produces an output like this:
[image: a sequent calculus proof produced by the above LaTeX code]