# Multi-column spacing of many equation-like environments

Tags: spacing, logic

I suppose I have a pretty simple question. I want to write down a logic inference system. A good example can be found on page 9 in this [document](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/gmb/papers/thesis.pdf):

[image]

**What environment** would you advise me to use to get a similar effect? In particular I would like to get nice multicolumn alignment (like in a table) and some standard spacing around every element. I don't care particularly about the border around the whole thing.

I tried using `tabular` however it produces too little spacing. This probably could be fixed, but feels like a hack.

**EDIT**: I think I might have been misunderstood. I don *not* ask how to write down inference rules themselves. I already know how to do it and I use `bussproofs` package for that. What I need is a way to put all those rules that I have in one table with nice spacing in it. Therefore I ask about an *environment* that would be suitable for something like that.

**EDIT(2)**: Ok, If someone thinks that `tabular` is the right approach, could you please tell me how to add some padding (margin) to all of the cells - both horizontal and vertical. I realize this might be a trivial question, however I have just spent half an hour looking for an answer.

Comment: Judging by nonstandard spacing, I think the author used `\frac` extensively with some `\quad` spacing. How do you want to align the two column entries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sequent Calculus](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44582/sequent-calculus)

Comment: @Seamus This is not a duplicate of the mentioned question - I already know how to produce rules and inferences. I just want to align them together in one table to form a inference system.

Comment: @julkiewicz that should be made clearer in the question. Make sure it is understood you are talking about the alignment and spacing _between_ the inferences not the alignment and spacing _of_ the inferences themselves.

Comment: @percusse Yes, I would like to align the contents of the two columns and maintain some spacing between the rules.

Comment: Sorry, for the misunderstanding. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have tried so far? In particular, what about the spacing of a tabular is problematic? tabulars are very customisable…

Comment: @Seamus I'm sort of a LaTeX newbie. I've always read that one should use the predefined idioms and avoid setting up spaces manually. Just as there is an environment for multi-line math derivations I thought that there is another one for putting together a bunch of math formulae so that they are readable. If you say, I should just use `tabular` and setup its spacing, that's fine with me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skipping over minor details, this may be accomplished with a `tabular`:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
\newcommand{\onecol}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{C}{#1}}
```

The above code should go in the preamble. Then the big thing can be set by

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % adjust here for interrow spacing
\begin{tabular}{CC}
\onecol{Formula for first line} \\
\onecol{Formula for second line} \\
\onecol{Formula for third line} \\
Left formula & right formula (row 4)\\
Left formula & right formula (row 5)\\
...
\end{tabular}
\caption{Sequent calculus formulation}\label{fig:seqcalc}
\end{figure}
```

Instead of setting `\arraystretch` you can define

```
\newcommand\mystrut{\vrule width 0pt height 24pt depth 24pt}
```

and insert `\mystrut` in a cell in each row but the first and the last. Adjust the dimensions to suit.

Comment: Should `\onecol` maybe be defined as `\newcommand{\onecol}[1]{\multicol{1}{C}{#1}}` -- say, to help generate a intelligible error message if `\onecol` is called without an argument...?

Comment: Actually it should be `\multicol{2}`!

Comment: Glad you caught my error! I was too fixated on the issue of providing an explicit argument for the macro.

Comment: Any alternatives to `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` that wouldn't make all of the rows the same height?

Comment: @julkiewicz I've added something

Answer (score 4):

It actually seems to me that you should use some of the amsmath environments : gather, aligned, and gathered.  I am typing from my phone right now so an example is difficult (I will update later) but you probably want something like this :

```
\begin{gather*}
  \begin{aligned}
   \begin{gathered} Left formula \\ Left formula … \end{gathered} &&
   \begin{gathered} Right formula \\ Right formula … \end{gathered}
  \end{aligned}
  \\
  \begin{gathered}
   Formula \\
   Formula \\
   …
  \end{gathered}
  …
\end{gather*}
```

When you want a two-column set of formulas (with.each column centered) use an aligned with a gathered for each column.  For a single column just use gathered. Put the whole thing in a gather so that the sets are collectively centered and you should get what the example shows.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a minor mock-up using @egreg's `tabular` and @percusse's `\frac` suggestion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{MnSymbol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
\newcommand{\onecol}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{C}{#1}}
\newcommand{\seq}[2]{\frac{\strut#1}{\strut#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5} % adjust here for interrow spacing
  \begin{tabular}{C@{\quad}C}
    \onecol{\seq{}{A \vdash A}\ \textit{Identity}} \\
    \onecol{\seq{\Gamma,A,B,\Delta \vdash C}{\Gamma,B,A,\Delta \vdash C}\ \textit{Exchange}} \\
    \onecol{\seq{\Gamma \vdash B \qquad B,\Delta \vdash C}{\Gamma,\Delta \vdash C}\ \textit{Cut}} \\
    \seq{}{\Gamma \vdash \mathbf{t}}\ (\mathbf{t}_\mathcal{R}) &
      \seq{}{\Gamma, \mathbf{f} \vdash A}\ (\mathbf{f}_\mathcal{L}) \\
    \seq{\Gamma \vdash A}{\Gamma,I \vdash A}\ (I_\mathcal{L}) &
      \seq{}{{}\vdash I}\ (I_\mathcal{R}) \\
    \seq{\Gamma,A,B \vdash C}{\Gamma, A \otimes B \vdash C}\ (\otimes_\mathcal{L}) &
      \seq{\Gamma \vdash A \qquad \Delta \vdash B}{\Gamma,\Delta \vdash A \otimes B}\ (\otimes_\mathcal{R}) \\
    \seq{\Gamma \vdash A \qquad \Delta,B \vdash C}{\Gamma,\Delta,A \multimap B \vdash C}\ (\multimap_\mathcal{L}) &
      \seq{\Gamma,A \vdash B}{\Gamma \vdash A \multimap B}\ (\multimap_\mathcal{R}) \\
    \seq{\Gamma,A \vdash C}{\Gamma,A \mathbin{\&} B \vdash C}\ (\&_{\mathcal{L}-1}) &
      \seq{\Gamma,B \vdash C}{\Gamma,A \mathbin{\&} B \vdash C}\ (\&_{\mathcal{L}-2}) \\
    \onecol{\vdots}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Sequent Calculus Formulation of \textbf{ILL}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Some things to note:

- You `tabular` column specification will determine the space between the two-column entries:

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{C@{\quad}C}
  ```

  will insert `\quad` between the widest elements in either column. To visualize the gap , you could use `C@{}|@{\quad}|@{}C`:

  [image]
- An `\arraystretch` of `2.5` seems sufficient to spread out the expressions within the `tabular`.
- `\frac` centres its contents with respect to the math axis, so there's no need to fiddle around with vertical adjustment in placing contents on the right.
- `\frac` is also supplied with a `\strut` in the numerator and denominator for spacing considerations. Alternatively, use `\mystrut` as defined in @egreg's answer. For convenience, everything is used in a macro `\seq` that takes, as arguments, the same configuration as `\frac`.

Comment: That's awesome, many thanks! Indeed I ended up using `tabular` as suggested by egreg. When the time comes for a general clean-up of my work, I will look into the suggestions that you gave here.